# How to make VSCode show all available methods within an object and method definitions for c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, monodevelop

I'm beginning to learn Unity and C# and I found a good series of tutorials, but in there the teacher uses MonoDevelop to write code. From what I figured out, MonoDevelop is not a part of Unity anymore and I can't use it (or can I?) so I installed VSCode instead. My issue is that in the videos when the teacher types something like "Random.", a little window appears under his cursor that shows all methods available in the Random class and some information about what those methods do [It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQs7F.png). When I type "Random." in VSCode, however, no such window appears, so I don't know what methods might be there and maybe there's something that I didn't know about but could use. [My code editor just looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmHuy.png). Is there a way to enable that feature in VSCode, and what is that even called? Thanks!

Comment: use an IDE that is made for C# like Visual Studio Community Edition (not Visual Studio Code) or install an intellisense filter for VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Comment: Install a C# extension in Visual Studio Code, that will give you intellisense.

Comment: I already have the C# extention by Microsoft installed, but it doesn't solve the problem. It allows me to autofill the names of the previously declared variables and methods, but that's about all it does..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but could solve it by following these instructions:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

What made it eventually work for me was installing (Windows) **.NET Framework 4.7.1 Developer Pack** instead of the latest version of that developer pack.

Hope this helps!